# Netsuite Script combine/merge multiple statements

Tags: netsuite

Have a functional requirement to email a customer a single email attachment that contains multiple statements.

I understand well Netsuite suitescript and how to generate a PDF using nlapiPrintRecord(), but as you know this only supports 1 record.

I have also read a suiteanswer where you can print the record, save it to the file cabinet, and then reference it, however this uses substantial unit governance and would severely limit the amount of data that could be generated in a single script.

I might have to generate an email that contains 100 statements. This seems like an impossible task, but if I generated my own template and used xmlToPdf() then I could used saved search results and have the email contain thousands of pages.

Is there a possible way to generate a statement without having to save the record or load the customer first as this also uses significant units, which can then be merged into a single pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into Advanced PDF Templates?  These use Freemarker for the templates and you can easily combine multiple PDF.  Just be aware that there is a size limit for email attachments in NetSuite, 5mb I think.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand how I would use an Advanced PDF template to combine multiple transactions. As I understand, a template is bound to a form or a specific transaction that is passed through by Netsuite.

Answer (score 0):

SuiteScript can generate a single document from your search results. Using the Freemarker HTML will be your best method. As stated, keep in mind the file size for email attachments. If you have graphics in your statement it will increase the size.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar requirement a couple of times.

At the core of this is using either N/render.TemplateRenderer (ss2) or nlobjTemplateRenderer.

They have slightly different interfaces but both will take search results and allow you to use BFO Pdf generator semantics to generate the statements.

For the header/main body information I generally create a custom record that groups the member records. For you statements you may just use a customer record for that but you'll still need an efficient way to find the saved search results you'll be adding to the render process.

SS1.0

```
var statementTrans = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', 'customsearch_kotn_statement_trans', sf('entity', null, 'is', customerId));
if(statementTrans) renderer.addSearchResults('trans', statementTrans);
```

Then in the template:

```
<#list trans as tran>
<#if sinceDate lte tran.trandate?date>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="3">${tran.trandate?date}</td>
<td align="left" colspan="8">${tran.type} #${tran.tranid}<#if tran.custbody_agencys_customer?has_content>,&#160;${tran.custbody_agencys_customer.companyname}</#if></td>
<td align="left" colspan="3">${tran.duedate?date}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="3">${tran.amount?string.currency}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="3">${tran.amountpaid?string.currency}</td>
<#assign runningBalance=runningBalance+tran.amountremaining>
<td align="right" colspan="3">${tran.amountremaining?string.currency}</td>
</tr>
</#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I have seen something similar but in the example provided, you needed to load a record.

Comment: There should be a method where you can link/load a custom object or search.  Can't remember the exact method name.

Comment: You should be looking at the docs for one of the APIs I referenced. Rough samples given for SS1.0 in my edited results. Beyond that you really should be cutting some code and posting questions if you run into issues.

Comment: OK, I understand the approach and can implement it, but how would I combine the transaction data above with the aging fields. I saw a post you did where you can use formula field to calculate, but those appear to be sum so I think that means I couldnt get the rows and the totals. I don't see how I could completely generate the customer statement because of this.

Comment: Have you tried to code it? So far it doesn’t really look like you’ve be done any work. Look at the freemarker docs. Do they present any ideas? Can you accumulate values into variables? Can you create a key-value store  to accumulate by customer?

Comment: I have not because I want to make sure it will work. I don't understand how nlobjTemplateRenderer is a solution because the documentation states that this accepts an nlobjrecord or search as an input. A customer statement has a sublist, header, and footer containing values. I may be able to get all that with a single search, but I don't know how to create a "key/value" store or do other complex logic in a restricted template. I have decided to create my own renderer and then call nlapiXmlToPdf which gives me the greatest flexibility. I don't have sufficient information to use your suggestion

Comment: each "thing" passed to nlobjTemplate renderer is passed with a key. So it can process a number of records and a number of search results. Anyway maybe as you get more familiar with Netsuite it'll make more sense.

Comment: I have a functional script that does what I need, but there is a requirement to specify a start date, which affects the starting balance. I do not know how through scripting to get a customers balance back in time.

Comment: You can run a search with aggregate functions to get an opening balance. Essentially totalling all invoices, cash sales, credit memos, cash refunds, and customer payments. You can do that by customer or group of customers. That can be one of the saved search results you pass to the template renderer.

Comment: Not so easy, the payments are made by the parent company and a single payment can include invoices from other customers not related. Even if I wrote some code to handle that, not sure how I would calculate each of the aging fields back in time. Thinking about giving up

Comment: There a quite a few ways to deal with your use case. This is now rather far afield of the original question. Think about how you would use custom entity and transaction fields to group things by ultimate payer.